# Invalid page tree PDF

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf, debugging

I have a generated LaTeX (python scripts, getting data from different sources) document which is then compiled into a pdf with pdfLaTeX.

Generally the structure of the document is the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[
  pdftex,
  a4paper,
  colorlinks=false,
  urlcolor=red,
  linkcolor=blue,
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  bookmarksopenlevel=2,
  bookmarksnumbered=false,
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines
]{hyperref}
% imported from stylesheet

\begin{document}
...

\tableofcontents
...
\section{Section A}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
Generated Text
Generated Plots ...

\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{...}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.30\textwidth}
...
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Until recently the hyperlinks within the document worked just fine. Now they are visible (red boxes in Acrobat Reader) in the pdf but clicking on them does not have an effect (not jumping to the correct section).

I tried it with different pdf-viewers and OSs.

Interesting is that evince has the console output

```
$ evince test.pdf 
Error: Invalid page tree
Error: Invalid page tree
Error: Invalid page tree
Error: Invalid page tree
Error: Invalid page tree
...
failed to look up section.1
failed to look up subsection.1.1
failed to look up subsection.1.2
failed to look up section.2
...
```

The `\hyperref`s to external sources (urls) still work.

How do you generally debug things like that? pdfLaTeX issue? LaTeX issue?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the comments. In an attempt to provide a minimal example I found the line that breaks it:

```
 \let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{ Some text \href{http://url.com}{Link}}
```

With this line in the .tex-file the external link itself works but the hyperrefs in the toc are broken (as described above). Without this line the links in the toc are fine.

**Edit2:**

```
\footnotetext{ Some text \href{http://url.com}{Link}}
```

works for me. The little `1` of the footnote should be hidden though. I guess that is it.

Another workaround seems to have the same effect (i.e. breaks the hyperlinks, too):

```
\makeatletter{\renewcommand*{\@makefnmark}{}\footnotetext{For further explanation refer to \href{http://www.google.com}{Link Text}}\makeatother}
```

Comment: Your document is very minimal, such that the sections appear on the same page as the  ToC. Apart from that, everything seems to be alright if I use `article` (for example) as the document class. Neither `evince` nor `Adobe Reader` report a faulty tree

Comment: I know the document I have provided is a bit too general (I'm not free to share the contents or the designs ...). I'll edit some more relevant code in. I am looking more generally for things to look for that can break the `page tree`. It can't be additional latex content as long as it is valid latex right? What generates the page tree? Where can this go wrong?

Comment: Any warnings or errors?

Comment: That is, any warnings or errors *on compilation*? That is where you are likely to find any clues. Scrutinise the console output - make sure you do not compile non-stop - and/or read the `.log` file.

Comment: The following packages provide 'dummy' text which can be used as filler in examples: `kantlipsum`, `lipsum`, `blindtext`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, when I add the `\footnotetext` line to the document.